# How to navigate from CarouselPage to MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to navigate from CarouselPage to MasterDetailPage. I have created two different my first page is carousel page on click of any button in curousel page i should navigate to masterdeatilpage.

Please help me out how to write the code and my master page is different and detail page is differnet both is written in content page.

code:

app.cs

```
public static MasterDetailPage MasterDetailPage;
public App()
{
    var isLoggedIn = App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLoggedIn")? (bool)Properties["IsLoggedIn"] : false;
        // The root page of your application
        if (isLoggedIn)
        {
            MasterDetailPage = new Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage
            {
                Master = new Menu(),
                Detail = new NavigationPage(new detail())
                {
                    Tint = Color.FromHex("313FA0")
                }
            };

            MasterDetailPage.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

            MainPage = MasterDetailPage;
        }
        else
        {
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new carousel());
        }
}
```

carousel.xaml.cs

```
<CarouselPage>
 <ContentPage>
   <StackLayout>
     <Button Text="click" Clicked="funca()"/>
   </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

carousel.cs

```
void funca(object sender, EventArgs e){
    App.MasterDetailPage.Master = new Menu();
    App.MasterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new detail());
    App.MasterDetailPage.IsPresented = false;  
}
```

In Click of the button it is shown error

```
System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Please help me out

Comment: Can you add the rest of the stack trace ?, and your App code too

Comment: Like @RuiMarinho says, I'm afraid we are going to need a bit more info here..

Comment: @RuiMarinho i did some edit in my code and app code also i have give please check it

Comment: @RuiMarinho both my Menu and detail page is in content page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of the given question with help of Tomasz Kowalczyk.

I created one class MasterPage.cs

```
public class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {
        Master = new Menu();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new detail());
    }
}
```

app.cs

```
public App()
{
  var isLoggedIn = App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLoggedIn")? (bool)Properties["IsLoggedIn"] : false;
    // The root page of your application
    if (isLoggedIn)
    {
        MainPage = new MasterPage();
    }
    else
    {
       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new carousel());
    }
}
```

carousel.cs

```
void funca(object sender, EventArgs e){
   MasterPage mp = new Menu();
   mp.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Detail());
   App.Current.MainPage = mp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my sample repo [here](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed). I am using [there](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/blob/master/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/Views/AboutView.cs#L32) solution based on `MessagingCenter` I believe it should also work in your scenario. Remember to put something similar to [this](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/blob/master/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/Views/MainView.cs#L23) in your `MasterDetailPage`.

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz with help of ur code i found alternate answer simply coding