# Navigation between pages in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, icommand

I have the following command inside a VM:

```
ICommand LaunchGameCommand => new Command(() =>
{
    //Navigation.PushAsync(...
});
```

According to [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165106/how-do-you-switch-pages-in-xamarin-forms) I should be able to use something akin to the navigation in the commented code; however, the Navigation object seems to reside in `Android.Content.Res`... which seems to be something else entirely.

Is this still the correct method of navigating between views / viewmodels in Xamarin Forms, or has this now been superseded with an alternate method?

Comment: the navigation object is in the xamarin.forms namespace.  Where is this view model if you see android namespaces?

Comment: In the shared project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is part of a page, you can’t find navigation property if you don’t have the reference to a some page, you need to have access to your current page in your view model to see this property,  you can have access to your current page using

Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.Push...

Comment: The issue I have with this is that if, from the VM, I need a reference to the page that I'm navigating to then I've broken the MVVM pattern.  I can, obviously, use a method such as reflection to work around this... but every time I see any blurb about Xamarin Forms I'm told it's MVVM out of the box.

Comment: Yep, but using Application.Current. you have de current context of the application and you have access to your main or current page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any particular MVVM framework? Most of these include a way of navigating from VM to VM.

I use FreshMvvm. It allows you to perform the following to navigate between VMs and also pass data:

```
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<MyNextPageModel>(DataToPass);
```

[More details here](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)